# Setup Coral Dev Mini- mdt devices - AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'get_running_loop'

Tags: google-coral

I have all the requirements for setting up the coral dev mini as suggested on the site: https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board-mini/get-started/#about-the-usb-ports

I run the python3 -m pip install --user mendel-development-tool

And it shows the mdt Path warning:  You might see a warning that mdt was installed somewhere that's not in your PATH environment variable. If so, be sure you add the given location to your PATH, as appropriate for your operating system. If you're on Linux, you can add it like this:

echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile

I have tried this and also try adding different paths, but I am coming up short.  What is the path I am point towards?

Thanks

Comment: After deleting all of the paths in vim ~/.bash_profile.  And upgrading Python3.  The next issue when running mdt devices is:



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Comment: Please try to use virtual env as alternative to fix this path issue:

python3 -m venv test_venv ;
source test_venv/bin/activate ;
python3 -m pip install --user mendel-development-tool;